# hide laravel application from wappalyzer extension

Tags: laravel, hide

I am trying to hide laravel application from wappalyzer extension, already i changed my session name and clear cache but still wappalyzer can detect laravel application.

Comment: It shows because of cache. Disable the wappalyzer extention & then reenable it to clear the cache. Or you could restart your browser. @Masud

Comment: Try deleting all cookies too.

Answer (score 1):

**Laravel 8** - .env file just change your APP_NAME=Value

```
APP_NAME=Your Application Name
```

Ex:

```
APP_NAME=bismillah
```

Wappalyzer Extension - Setting - Clear cached detections

[.env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu1UG.png)

[Wappalyzer- Clear cached detections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFrag.png)

[Wappalyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WKqV.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the config/session.php, try changing:

`'cookie' => 'laravel_session',`

To something like:

`'cookie' => 'app_name_session',`

Comment: it's still there