# Hide the technology behind the a web application

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

If you go to builtwith.com and check your Laravel powered website, chances are you'll see Laravel as the technology used.

Shows:

```
Laravel
Laravel Usage Statistics - Download list of all Laravel websites
A PHP MVC framework.
```

And

```
PHP
PHP Usage Statistics - Download list of all PHP websites
PHP is a widely-used general-purpose scripting language that is especially suited for Web development and can be embedded into HTML.
```

Is there any way to hide this?
Does anyone know what specifically is giving this away?

Could also be the cookie name as well as headers?

Comment: Change sessions cookie name (or in newest versions application name). Also you can use extension wappalizer for google chrome (maybe even for FF), instead of builtwith.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a question that is solved by changing configuration; its also duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44983337/hide-laravel-application-from-wappalyzer-extension

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd like to point out that hiding what powers your web app isn't really worth the time or effort, with that said if you really really want to, there are a couple of things you could try:

- Changing the defaults of apache "tell all" behaviour with these directives (assuming you are using apache, not really familiar with nginx):

  ```
  ServerTokens Prod
  ServerSignature Off
  ```
- php will add a `X-Powered-By` HTTP header if `expose_php` was set to `on` in your php.ini file.
- Lastly builtwith.com provides a [link](http://builtwith.com/removals) for you to remove your domain from their lookup index, so you could give that a try.